# Check if $\frac{x'^{2}}{2}-\sin(x)$ is a lyapunov function for $x''=\cos(x)-0.1x'$ near $(x,x')=(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

> Check if $\frac{x'^{2}}{2}-\sin(x)$ is a lyapunov function for $x''=\cos(x)-0.1x'$ near $(x,x')=(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$

I rewrote this into a system:
$x'=y$, $y'=\cos(x)-0.1y$, $F(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\sin(x)$,

And want to show that this is lyapunov function near $(x,y)=(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$

And then $F'(x,y)=yy'-\cos(x)x'=y\cos(x)-0.1y^2-y\cos(x)=-0.1y^2$

which is strictly decreasing so the sign doesn't change and $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ is a critical point of my system.

So do I know this is a lyapunov function?

This is my definition of Lyapunov function:

> I have this lyapunov stability theorem,
> Assume $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x^*, F:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $F(x^*)=0$. Further assume that there is a $C^1$-function $V:U\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $V(x^*)=0$, $V(x)>0$ for $x\neq x^*$. Then, V is called a lyapunov function for $x'=F(x)$ and:

> a. If $V'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in U$, then $x^*$ is L-stable
> b. If $V'(x)<0$ for all $x\in U\{x^*\}$, then $x^*$ is asymptotically stable.
> c. If $V'(x)>0$ for all $x\in U\{x^*\}$ then $x^*$ is unstable.

Comment: What's your definition of lyapunov function?

Comment: @Darsen I have this lyapunov stability theorem I'll include it as an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's transform the ODE into an SDE:

$y_1=x,y_2=x'\Rightarrow y_1'=y_2,y_2'=x''=\cos(x)-0.1x'=\cos(y_1)-0.1y_2\Rightarrow\begin{cases}y_1'=y_2\\y_2'=\cos(y_1)-0.1y_2\end{cases}$

Then the function would be $V(y_1,y_2)=\dfrac{y_2^2}{2}-\sin(y_1)$. We need points near $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$, so we could consider points $(y_1,y_2)=(\frac{\pi}{2}+r,0)$ with $|r|>0$ as small as we want. For those points $V(y_1,y_2)=-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+r)<0$ for $0<r<\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $V$ can't be a lyapunov function.

Comment: Why do you only have to consider points around $x$ with $y$ fixed?

Comment: Because they are points near $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$. Of course, there are other points near $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$, but it suffices to show that we stay as close as we want to $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ and still find points such that $V\ngtr0$. It's clear that the distance from $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ to a point $(\frac{\pi}{2}+r,0)$ is $|r|$, which we can make as small as we want.

Comment: Does it matter that $F(\frac{\pi}{2},0)=-1$? I don't know why this definition looks this way because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function#Definition doesn't seem to have this part in the definition at all.

Comment: I think you're confusing $F$ and $V$. Since in your definition it's said that $x'=F(x)$ this means that $F$ is the function of the SDE I wrote, meaning $F(y_1,y_2)=(y_2,\cos(y_1)-0.1y_1)$, while $V$ is the candidate to lyapunov function. Note that indeed we have $F(\frac{\pi}{2},0)=0$.

Comment: My definition says that $V(x^*)=0$ which is not true for this function. But I don't understand why that's in my definition but not in the definition on wikipedia.

Comment: I think maybe you're supposed to do a change of variables $z=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$, so your solution is the zero function, and then $V(0,0)=0$, but even then $V$ wouldn't be a lyapunov function, as shown in the answer.

Comment: The wikipedia definition doesn't say $g(y)=0$ though, which is what my definition says doesn't it?

Comment: You're right. I confused $g$ with $V$. In Wikipedia it's said that $V$ has to be strictly positive, but it should said it for points distinct from $y$. In the example below $V$ does exactly that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115696/discussion-between-darsen-and-acoloredreptile).